# Spotlight for Safari tabs

Tags: safari, spotlight, search, tabs

Is there a way to <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>space</kbd> (i.e. bring up Spotlight), type the name of an already open tab and bring it to the foreground?

Or an app that does it outside of spotlight?

I spend far too long looking for tabs, only to give up and make another the same.

I do have "Recent Tab List" http://nickvdp.com/tablist/ but I don't see a way to invoke it from the keyboard or integrate it with Spotlight, as what I'm wanting to do is access this from anywhere (not just when I'm in Safari).

I don't want to have to create an app for every website ([Use spotlight (or Alfred) to open an existing chrome tab](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/234853/use-spotlight-or-alfred-to-open-an-existing-chrome-tab))

[Safari "Search Tabs" Keyboard Shortcuts](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/155266/safari-search-tabs-keyboard-shortcuts) leads to http://hea-www.harvard.edu/~fine/OSX/safari-tabs.html which again isn't integrated into Spotlight.

Comment: Your second sentence says _Or an app that does it outside of spotlight_, so presumably Spotlight is not a compulsory requirement. However, you then go on to imply it must work in Spotlight. As part of my edit to your question I added _as what I'm wanting to do is access this from anywhere (not just when I'm in Safari)_, is that correct? Can you clarify?

Comment: Use of spotlight is definitely preferred, as it is the OS X normal global keyboard combination to launch things. That said, if I can't invoke from Spotlight some other app launch-able by keyboard combination would suffice.

Comment: I added my own keyboard control to the Recent Tab List extension using Alfred: https://github.com/nickvdp/RecentTabList/issues/13#issuecomment-395111542

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search in Safari's open tabs: Two-finger pinch on the track pad, then start writing any word in the tab you’re looking for.

Comment: Typical frustratingly minimalistic UI design that Apple omit the search dialog on that view until you start typing, although on balance the Edit -> Find... is not greyed out.

Comment: Unfortunately, that only looks at the tabs in the current window (which doesn't help when one has several dozen windows open, each with several tabs).